# Why can use “docker run imgae“ an image，but can't “docker-compose“ run the same image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, harbor

My `db.docker` file

```
FROM loongson.harbor.cn/larchloongsoncloud/loongnix-server:8.3
RUN yum install -y glibc-common
#RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

ENV PGDATA /var/lib/postgresql/data

#COPY ./make/photon/db/postgresql.conf.sample /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample


RUN yum install -y shadow-utils  gzip  postgresql-server  postgresql >> /dev/null \
    && groupmod --gid 9999 postgres  \
    && usermod  -g postgres --uid=9999 postgres \
    && mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d \
    && mkdir -p /run/postgresql \
    && chown -R postgres:postgres /run/postgresql \
    && chmod 2777 /run/postgresql \
#   && mkdir -p /var/lib/postgresql/data && chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql && chmod -R 777 /var/lib/postgresql && ls -la  /var/lib/ \
    && sed -i "s|#listen_addresses = 'localhost'.*|listen_addresses = '*'|g" /usr/share/pgsql/postgresql.conf.sample \
    && sed -i "s|#unix_socket_directories = '/tmp'.*|unix_socket_directories = '/run/postgresql'|g" /usr/share/pgsql/postgresql.conf.sample \
    && yum clean all


RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/postgresql/data
RUN chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/lib/postgresql
RUN ls -la  /var/lib/

RUN yum erase -y toybox && yum install -y util-linux net-tools

VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data

COPY ./make/photon/db/docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
COPY ./make/photon/db/docker-healthcheck.sh /docker-healthcheck.sh
COPY ./make/photon/db/initial-notaryserver.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY ./make/photon/db/initial-notarysigner.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY ./make/photon/db/initial-registry.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
RUN chown -R postgres:postgres /docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-healthcheck.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d \
    && chmod u+x /docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-healthcheck.sh

#USER postgres:postgres

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
HEALTHCHECK CMD ["/docker-healthcheck.sh"]

EXPOSE 5432
USER postgres
```

My current `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2.3'
services:
  log:
    image: goharbor/harbor-log:dev
    container_name: harbor-log
    restart: always
    dns_search: .
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - DAC_OVERRIDE
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
    volumes:
      - /var/log/harbor/:/var/log/docker/:z
      - ./common/config/log/logrotate.conf:/etc/logrotate.d/logrotate.conf:z
      - ./common/config/log/rsyslog_docker.conf:/etc/rsyslog.d/rsyslog_docker.conf:z
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:1514:10514
    networks:
      - harbor
  registry:
    image: goharbor/registry-photon:v2.7.1-patch-2819-2553-dev
    container_name: registry
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
    volumes:
      - /home/registry:/storage:z
      - ./common/config/registry/:/etc/registry/:z
      - type: bind
        source: /home/secret/registry/root.crt
        target: /etc/registry/root.crt
    networks:
      - harbor
    dns_search: .
    depends_on:
      - log
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "registry"
  registryctl:
    image: goharbor/harbor-registryctl:dev
    container_name: registryctl
    env_file:
      - ./common/config/registryctl/env
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
    volumes:
      - /home/registry:/storage:z
      - ./common/config/registry/:/etc/registry/:z
      - type: bind
        source: ./common/config/registryctl/config.yml
        target: /etc/registryctl/config.yml
    networks:
      - harbor
    dns_search: .
    depends_on:
      - log
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "registryctl"
  **postgresql:
    image: goharbor/harbor-db:dev
    container_name: harbor-db
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - DAC_OVERRIDE
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
    volumes:
      - /home/database:/var/lib/postgresql/data:z
    networks:
      harbor:
    dns_search: .
    env_file:
      - ./common/config/db/env
    depends_on:
      - log
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "postgresql"**
  core:
    image: goharbor/harbor-core:dev
    container_name: harbor-core
    env_file:
      - ./common/config/core/env
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
    volumes:
      - /home/ca_download/:/etc/core/ca/:z
      - /home/psc/:/etc/core/token/:z
      - /home/:/data/:z
      - ./common/config/core/certificates/:/etc/core/certificates/:z
      - type: bind
        source: ./common/config/core/app.conf
        target: /etc/core/app.conf
      - type: bind
        source: /home/secret/core/private_key.pem
        target: /etc/core/private_key.pem
      - type: bind
        source: /home/secret/keys/secretkey
        target: /etc/core/key
    networks:
      harbor:
    dns_search: .
    depends_on:
      - log
      - registry
      - redis
      - postgresql
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "core"
  portal:
    image: goharbor/harbor-portal:dev
    container_name: harbor-portal
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
      - NET_BIND_SERVICE
    networks:
      - harbor
    dns_search: .
    depends_on:
      - log
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "portal"

  jobservice:
    image: goharbor/harbor-jobservice:dev
    container_name: harbor-jobservice
    env_file:
      - ./common/config/jobservice/env
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
    volumes:
      - /home/job_logs:/var/log/jobs:z
      - type: bind
        source: ./common/config/jobservice/config.yml
        target: /etc/jobservice/config.yml
    networks:
      - harbor
    dns_search: .
    depends_on:
      - core
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "jobservice"
  redis:
    image: goharbor/redis-photon:dev
    container_name: redis
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
    volumes:
      - /home/redis:/var/lib/redis
    networks:
      harbor:
    dns_search: .
    depends_on:
      - log
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "redis"
  proxy:
    image: goharbor/nginx-photon:dev
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
      - NET_BIND_SERVICE
    volumes:
      - ./common/config/nginx:/etc/nginx:z
    networks:
      - harbor
    dns_search: .
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    depends_on:
      - registry
      - core
      - portal
      - log
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "proxy"
networks:
  harbor:
    external: false
```

[image]

[image]
Why the initdb could not access ???

[image]

The first container is **healthy** (use `docker run`), but the second container is **unhealthy** (use `docker-compose run` ). The image is the same.

Comment: Can you [edit] this question and reduce this setup to a [mcve]?  What's the minimum Dockerfile and Compose file required to reproduce the issue?  Are the PNG files part of the issue, or can they also be removed from the question?  What is the actual successful `docker run` command?  What is the text-format output of the unsuccessful case?

Answer (score 0):

if you have already created this directory /home/database in your system, its file permission does not give permission to posgress. change the directory owner to 999.

Comment: Thank U. I modified Harbor's  install.h  and succeeded